# Should players use a consistent "meta" convention for picking who to lynch on D2, in the absence of intel?

Tags: werewolv.es

E.g. should they always lynch the first player in the list, if there are no reports from the seer, the harlot, the stalker, etc. on D2, so that the werewolves can't arbitrarily propose a target of their choosing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a question with a definitive answer as different people will have different opinions.

The short answer is: no.

The longer answer is: There are many reasons to lynch people, of which intel from power roles is only one. Looking at what people say, how they say things, what they do etc. These things all influence the decision of who to vote for and who to lynch. Intel from roles shouldn't be the only reason that people get lynched, it's part of a larger picture.

There's also the "Fun" element of the game. If you end up with the "A" avatar, you're not going to enjoy the game if people decide "We're always lynching the first person in the list on Day 2".

Comment: Doesn't the ability of the wolves to eat some random player on N1 also take away from the "fun" aspect for some unlucky individual?

Comment: That's part of the game though, bit also generally somewhat random so not a case of "your avatar starts with A you're dying first" or so.